# ajax comment in django

Tags: python, django, ajax, comments

I am trying to create a comment on a post in my Django application. I have a working form for the comment, but when I submit the form, I get an error message.

The error message is:

{"response": "forbidden"}
I have checked my code and I am sure that the form is valid and that the request is being sent to the correct URL. I have also checked the permissions for the user who is trying to create the comment, and they are logged in and have the appropriate permissions.

I am not sure what is causing the error. Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    author = forms.CharField(required=True, error_messages={'required': 'لطفاً نام خود را وارد کنید.'})
    body = forms.CharField(required=True, error_messages={'required': 'لطفاً نظر خود را وارد کنید.'})

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'body', 'post')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cleaned_data = {}

    def clean_author(self):
        author = self.cleaned_data.get('author', 'نام کاربری ناشناس')
        return author

    def clean_body(self):
        body = self.cleaned_data.get('body')
        return body

function comment(slug, id) {
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

    $.post(`/posts/post/${slug}/comment/create/${id}`, {
    comment: comment
    }).then(response => {
        if (response['response'] === 'created') {
            var count = document.getElementById("count");
            count.innerText = Number(count.innerText) + 1;

            document.getElementById("comment").value = "";
        } else {
            var errors = response['errors'];
            for (var key in errors) {
                var error = errors[key];
                document.getElementById("comment").classList.add("is-invalid");
                document.getElementById("comment").setAttribute("aria-invalid", "true");
                document.getElementById("comment").setCustomValidity(error);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Environment:

Django 4.2.6
Python 3.11
Steps to reproduce:

Go to the post page.
Click the "Leave a comment" button.
Enter a comment in the comment field.
Click the "Submit" button.
Expected behavior:

The comment should be created and displayed on the post page.

Actual behavior:

The error message "{"response": "forbidden"}" is displayed.

Additional information:

I have checked the permissions for the user who is trying to create the comment, and they are logged in and have the appropriate permissions.
`your text`
I have also checked the form and the request, and they seem to be valid.

I am not sure what is causing the error. Can anyone help me?

I am trying to create a comment on a post in my Django application. I have a working form for the comment, but when I submit the form, I get an error message.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are missing [`csrftoken`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) in your request header. Please share `models.py`, `views.py`  and maybe `urls.py` so we can easily replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing csrfmiddlewaretoken in post

```
$.post(`/posts/post/${slug}/comment/create/${id}`, {
comment: comment, csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}"
}).then(response => {

})
```

Comment: I changed that code but it wasn't successful

Comment: Share your view in the question please